# How to get started with Javacard?

Tags: javacard

I'm new to smart-card development. Please help me understand how to get started.

1. What's the relationship between Javacard and JCOP?
2. How do I map a JCOP version to a GlobalPlatform [Card Specification](http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp)?

   - For example, what specification does JCOP 2.4.1 map to?
3. When do I need to code against one API versus the other?
4. Where can I find a good tutorial to get started?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. JCOP is a software platform originally from IBM that implements Javacard API and GlobalPlatform (formerly Open Platform). Now owned and managed by NXP.
2. JCOP 2.4.1? Probably GP 2.1.1. Do a web search for specific product specifications.
3. javacard and GP:

   - Javacard is used to write applications - javacard applets - for smartcard platforms, using the Java Programming language and a limited version of the JVM and java libraries.
   - GlobalPlatform is a specification for managing applet-aware smartcards, defining operations for things like:

     - managing card lifecycle,
     - card/host authentication,
     - installing/deleting/instantiating/selecting applets, and
     - managing security policies on the card.
   - Using GlobalPlatform you'll exchange APDUs with the GP card for the aforementioned operations; using javacard you'll write applets that can accept and process APDUs that are specific to your application. GlobalPlatform **isn't** javacard specific, but javacard is the only relevant technology for smartcard applet development.
4. For javacard tutorials, start with the [javacard site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/overview/index.html). Look through the documentation section for *Getting Started* stuff. Download the dev kit and you'll find some html howtos. For GlobalPlatform, you'll need to begin with the latest GP spec; it's certainly not a tutorial, but I don't think you'll find anything more useful. The spec will require strong smartcard fundamentals. Also see [Required Things to start Smartcard Programming Using Javacard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992040/required-things-to-start-smartcard-programming-using-javacard/7164915#7164915)

Comment: Re: #2, I can't find the JCOP specifications anywhere. Does JCOP even have a dedicated website? Re: #3, that's a bit weird because the book "Java Card Technology for Smart Cards: Architecture and Programmer's Guide" claims that GlobalPlatform is just an extension of JavaCard that adds extra features. It seems to imply that JavaCard contains the basic mechanisms used to install/remove applets and do authentication. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 8):

I used this excellent tutorial when started with JavaCard: http://javacard.vetilles.com/tutorial/ ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201204144650/https://javacard.vetilles.com/tutorial/))

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful - I spent a while getting older tutorials working on real hardware (e.g. physical Java Cards with GP), including sending APDUs etc. I've collected some of my notes into a video format as it was too much work to write down every little thing.

The video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj2l0X8D4y0&hd=1 and includes basically a quick run-through of what to install, building a program, installing to a Java Card, and talking to said program via Python. It's very very basic but sometimes that's what you need...

Answer (score 2):

jcManager
http://www.brokenmill.com/2010/03/java-secure-card-manager/
comes with source code, which is useful

Comment: oops, the authenticate_SCP02 function is killing my JCOP41 cards! I believed that 10 failed authentications were needed to kill a card, but this function is killing them promptly.

Comment: OK my, fault, an error in transcription, not an error in jcManager code.  But note: Sudden death of JCOP card is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The two best introductory **tutorials** I have found are:

1. [**"Lecture 14 - Javacard"** https://edux.pjwstk.edu.pl/mat/268/lec/lect14/lecture14.html](https://edux.pjwstk.edu.pl/mat/268/lec/lect14/lecture14.html)

and this one at JavaWorld,

2. **[How to write a Java Card applet: A developer's guide](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076450/client-side-java/how-to-write-a-java-card-applet--a-developer-s-guide.html)**

For example code there is a section titled [**Learning**](https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/javacard-curated-list#learning-various-school-projects-simple-hello-world-applets) in this Github repo,

[**javacard-curated-list of applets**](https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/javacard-curated-list)

---

To give an idea of the first topics that are typically covered, the headings from the second link mentioned are:

> Architecting the applet
>
> Specifying the functions of the applet
>
> Specifying AIDs
>
> Defining the class structure and method functions of the applet
>
> Defining the interface between an applet and its terminal application
>
> An APDU primer
>
> - Defining APDU commands
> - The Javacard APDU Class
>
>   The applet processes an APDU command by invoking methods on the APDU object. In general it performs these steps:
>
>   Step 1. Retrieve the APDU buffer
>
>   Step 2. Receive data
>
>   Step 3. Return data
>
>   Step 4. Return status word
>
> Constructing the applet code
>
> Implementing error checking

This article is by **Zhiqun Chen** who also wrote [the book **Java Card Technology for Smart Cards**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/761439.Java_Card_Technology_for_Smart_Cards)