# What is the structure of an application protocol data unit (APDU) command and response?

Tags: javacard, iso

I am trying to learn **Java Card**.  I have just started and have not found many resources.  My first question is how to understand APDU commands.  (such as those defined in ISO/IEC 7816-4)

For example, if I see a byte pattern such as **`10101010`** how can I understand the meaning of this, and in particular determine the **`CLA`** or **`INS`**, for example?

Comment: There's so many references on the internet. Just Google it, then read, finally you'll undrestand

Comment: Hi, what more information would like to get? If you have any questions, please ask me in a comment under my answer...

Comment: The APDU specifications are in ISO/IEC 7816-4. You may want to get a copy of the latest version. It's payware though.

Comment: You also forgot to accept answer to this question also. It seems that you don't want to accept answers to you questions.

Comment: This problem seems to be solved. Please, mark any of answers as accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

APDU commands are a queue of binary numbers in the following form:

> CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | Lc | CData | Le

The first four sections, i.e *CLA* , *INS* , *P1* and *P2* are mandatory in all APDU commands and **each one has one byte length**. These one-byte-length sections stand for Class, Instruction, Parameter1 and Parameter2 respectively.

The last three sections, i.e *Lc* , *CData* and *Le* are optional.Lc is the encoding of Nc, which is the encoding of the length of the CDATA field. Le is the encoding of Ne, then encoding of the maximum response data that may be send. Based on presence or absence of these sections, we have 4 case for APDU commands, as below:

- Case1: `CLA | INS | P1 | P2`
- Case2: `CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | Le`
- Case3: `CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | Lc | Data`
- Case4: `CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | Lc | Data | Le`

The length of CData is different for different commands and different applets. based on the length of CData (i.e Lc) and the length of maximum response data that may send (i.e Le), we have to type of APDU commands:

- **Normal/Short APDU** commands, when *Lc* **and** *Le* are smaller than `0xFF`
- **Extended length APDU** commands, when *Lc* **and/or** *Le* are greater than `0xFF`.

So for the length of these sections we have:

**Lc** : 1 byte for Short APDU commands and 3 byte (they specify this length, because its enough) for Extended APDU commands.

**Data** : Different lengths.

**Le** : Same as *Lc*.

---

*How can I understand APDU commands?*

Answer:

When you write an applet, you specify the response of your applet to different APDU commands that it will receive in the future. Card Manager is an applet also. The commands that it support is defined in your card's specifications/datasheet. Normally almost all cards are [GlobalPlatform](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/GPCardSpec_v2.2.pdf) and [ISO7816](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx) compliant, so they must support those mandatory APDU commands that is defined in these documents. For example, as `0xA4` is defined as *SELECT FILE* command in ISO7816-4 standard, If you see an APDU like `xx A4 xx xx` is sending to Card Manager, you can conclude that it is related with `SELECT FILE`.

Note that you can choose one value for different functions in your different applets. For example in the following, Applet1 will return `0x6990` in the reception of `00 B0 xx xx` APDU commands, while Applet2 will return `0x6991` in the reception of the same command:

Applet1:

```
public class SOQ extends Applet {

    private SOQ() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new SOQ().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        byte buffer[] = arg0.getBuffer();
        
        if(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == (byte) 0x00 &&buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) 0xB0){
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6990);
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
OpenSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00B00000 -s 00B00
100
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x90)
Sending: 00 B0 00 00
Received (SW1=0x69, SW2=0x90)
Sending: 00 B0 01 00
Received (SW1=0x69, SW2=0x90)
```

Applet2:

```
public class SOQ extends Applet {

    private SOQ() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new SOQ().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        byte buffer[] = arg0.getBuffer();
        
        if(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == (byte) 0x00 && buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) 0xB0){
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6991);
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
OpenSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00B00000 -s 00B00
100
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 B0 00 00
Received (SW1=0x69, SW2=0x91)
Sending: 00 B0 01 00
Received (SW1=0x69, SW2=0x91)
```

So the final and short answer to your question (*How can I understand APDU commands?*) is:

- **You are dealing with your applet?**

  You defined the supported commands and their forms, yourself!
- **You are dealing with another applet (Card Manager, for example)?**

  You need the source code of that applet or its documentation about its supported commands and their forms or the standard/specification that that applet is compliant with (Global Platform for Card Managers for example).

*Note: we have almost the same for APDU responses.*

Comment: I think the CLA and INS specified were in binary, not hex. Lc is the encoding of Nc, which is the encoding of the length of the CDATA field. Le is the encoding of Ne, then encoding of the *maximum* response data that may be send. This is currently incorrect in the Java Card specifications as well :)

Comment: Thank you again dear Mr Bodewes :) I changed that parts that you mentioned. But I didn't understand the first sentence of your comment (i.e: _CLA and INS specified were in binary, not hex._). Doesn't only the value matters? I mean as you know the Hex or Bin is only the form of view and doesn't matter. I was said _"a queue of **hex** numbers"_, because I almost always see APDU commands in their hex form". Am I miss a point in your comment? I think I didn't got the point :)

Comment: From your answer: "The first four sections, i.e CLA , INS , P1 and P2 are mandatory in all APDU commands and each one has one byte length (So there is no CLA = 10101010 or INS = 10101010)." . I think this is a bit of a misunderstanding. The question first specified an APDU in hex, and now the INS and CLA in binary. If it is binary it is a valid encoding of CLA and INS, even if BROY just jotted down some bits.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Ah, you are right again :) I was look at those values as `0x10 0x10 0x10 0x10`. I removed that sentence. Thank you.

Comment: How do you send commands from terminal to the JavaCardApplet ?@Abraham

Comment: @Mr.T Almost all card readers have their own tool for sending APDU commands to card. But there are also a lot of free tools to aim this goal. OpenSCTool is an old free open source tool for that.  The other is PyAPDUTool. You can also write your own program simply. Pyscard is a python library for that. Javax.smartcardio is its Java counterpart :)

Comment: @Abraham- Could you please guide me in setting up the environment ? I couldnt run the apdutool from the command terminal. It is saying could not find or load main class com.sun.javacard.apdutool.main!!!

Comment: @Mr.T The version of pyAPDUtool that I have,  has a GUI ,not command line. So I think we are using two different tools.Try to add all the `.jar` files in your tool install directory, to your JRE lib directory. It may solve the issue. Anyway, comments is not supposed to be a way to asking new questions :) If my comment doesn't solve the issue, please remove your last comments and ask it in details as a new question (Then I'll delete mine too)

Comment: @Abraham, so if i am in my own applet, I could forward the APDU to the CardManager applet if i need to?

Comment: this was extremely helpfull thank you very much.

Comment: This answer is El Magnifeco! If request has no data content, then packet size is either 4 or 5. In which case if packet size is 5, then the fifth describes response len max size. Then if packet size is 7, then the fifth should be 2. If that packet size is 8 and fifth is 2, then the 8th byte describes the response Max Len. That iis why a request APDU "80:00:00:00:00:F2" is invalid because the correct format should have been "80:00:00:00:F2"

Answer (score 8):

I am afraid such a "complete" e-book simply does not exist. Honestly, I think it is not necessary at all. If you know the basic Java syntax, you will find JavaCard quite easy to learn (although annoying to use). All the usual difficult stuff (threading, GUI, IO, annotations, templates, databases, ...) is just missing in Javacard and the standard libraries are so limited you will be able to learn them in a few days.

There are a few nice tutorials out there:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/overview/index.html
http://javacard.vetilles.com/tutorial/

and a very good SO question:

[How to get started with Java Cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190338/how-to-get-started-with-java-cards)

To answer your question: JavaCard is just a language for writing smartcard applications called applets. It handles all the application logic, but it does not specify the APDU format. That is because JavaCard is not the only smartcard technology. APDU format is specifed in ISO7816 standard, which I really recommend you to read through. It is not free to download, but you can find the most important parts here:

http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx

You would find there, that your APDU command consists of a header:

`00A404000E`

and a data part:

`63616C63756C61746F722E617070`.

The header specifies what function should be called:

`00` - class byte (CLA, 00 means "inter-industry command sent to logical channel 0")

`A4` - instruction byte (INS, A4 means "SELECT applet command")

`04` - parameter 1 (P1)

`00` - parameter 2 (P2)

`0E` - length of the data part (Lc)

and the data part contains the identifier of the applet which should be selected for future usage (in your case it is an ASCII encoded string "calculator.app" btw).

Comment: How to comprehend any values of CLA or INS? There are no well formed documents on the Internet. For example, how can I understand the meaning if CLA = 10101010? or, if INS = 10101010?

Comment: @BROY Have a look at chapters 5.4.1 and 5.4.2 in this document: http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx#chap5_3

Comment: Good answer and informative. Isn't it that "select" command uses hexadecimal numeric AID rather than alphabetic strings? Pls correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @typelogic Yes, the alphabetical string is encoded to bytes using ASCII.