# Alternative solution to Java applet

Tags: c#, browser, applet, windows-services, portforwarding

I want to create an architecture as below

Web browser sends an http request. Web server accepts it and returns response to the another port to client machine. Windows service setted up at client machine will accept this reponse and process it.

I want to realize the project via Java applet. But Chrome doesn't support NPAPI. And Firefox also will terminate the support till the end of 2016. Therefore I decided to solve my problem by above way.

How can I realize it?

Comment: use restful webservices for more details see http://javaant.com/category/restful

Comment: @NirmalDhara Service which is in the client machine must interact with device connected to PC via USB. This device is smart card reader.

Comment: Chrome has its native client API while other browsers have their own.

Comment: @LexLi, for all popular browsers write a code separately is problem. It's support also will difficult. I'm searching for the universal solution.

Comment: check this link it may help you http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javacard-servlets-136657.html

Comment: @NirmalDhara, how can browser send APDU command to the smart card reader?

Comment: chck this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550899/how-to-understand-java-card-apdu-commands

Comment: @NirmalDhara, I know the structure of APDU commands. As you know the web browser has rectricted resources and it can only interact with the client at "top-level". I mean it cann't use the client machine resources.